# How can I restart the ruby script from inside the script?

Tags: ruby

I am looking for a way to stop the current running script and restart it if a continuation is met.

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "a continuation is met"?

Answer (score 5):

Write like this:

```
at_exit{
  # whatever way you started the program originally such as `program_name`.
  # Make sure that the new process is detached from the original.
}
```

and then do:

```
exit
```

somewhere where you want to break.